# How are WWE shows written in such a short amount of time?

Tags: wwe

I can see giant shows of WWE in single week without miss.

Giant meaning 3 hours for RAW, 2 Hours for Smackdown, main events are 1 hour, etc.

How are WWE shows written in such a short amount of time? How is it possible?

Comment: Because the wrestling takes up most of the time, very little story is needed. There is also a high amount of ad libbing. They are live and only need general ideas that they work off. They also have a big writing crew. Finally, weekly shows are pretty common, it's not difficult to get them written and filmed in that time. Look at daily talk shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points:

- A few hours of material a week is easy. It's done all the time. Look at any daily news or comedy show.
- Wrestling has, well, wrestling. And dead time between matches. They do not need a solid 3 hours of material.
- Due to the live aspect, Ad Libbing, and going with the crowd or situation is a must. Not everything needs to be written, even though much is.
- The writer's pool is huge. [25+ normal writers, and they are always hiring.](http://wrestlingrumors.net/wwe-looking-new-writers/) To compare, SNL had half of that in 1988. [The Daily Show has 12 normal ones, 17 total.](http://splitsider.com/2015/09/heres-the-writing-staff-of-the-daily-show-with-trevor-noah/)
- They have done this for years, and know exactly how to pace the episode. Raw started out with some tape segments, and a much lower time slot, and slowly expanded to it's 3 hour status.

Courtesy of leaked scripts, [here's a standard Simpson's episode](http://splitsider.com/2010/11/first-draft-script-emsweet-seymour-skinners-baadasssss-song/), clocking in at 54 pages of mostly speech. [Here's a WWE Raw episode's script](http://deadspin.com/this-is-what-a-wwe-raw-script-looks-like-1570327862), 16 pages, only 12 of which are the actual show, and it's mostly stage directions and not speech. They had a video of the episode to compare, and it wasn't word for word:

> You'll notice right away, from the moment Wyatt adds a few lines before hitting his scripted words, that there are differences. This is a function of two things.
>
> First, this script was a draft (the third, to be precise). Like any show, Raw goes through a number of rewrites before hitting on the final product. We don't know how many drafts this one eventually went through, but considering how close this one is to what eventually aired, it couldn't have been many.
>
> Second, the scripted speeches are never meant to be read word-for-word. Think of them as talking points. They provide the notes that need to be hit, but wrestlers—especially those as skilled on the mic as Wyatt and Cena—are expected and encouraged to ad-lib, adding their own characters' spins to the promos.

Think Powerpoint Presentation, not a written/rehearsed Speech.

[image]

The actual match is pretty much the same. Ad-libbed for the most part, with just the ending predetermined.

They also steal comedy bits. The MLP episode aired March 2011. Cena copied it August 2011:

Comment: "The actual match is pretty much the same. Ad-libbed for the most part, with just the ending predetermined.". This is only partly true -- it depends largely on the skill of the wrestlers involved. Many matches these days are scripted start to finish. But that's done by the wrestlers and the road agents, _not_ the writers, so it does not add anything to the time to write the show.

Comment: I would also add that most referees and announcers are getting live feeds to their earpieces / headsets to help navigate the show towards critical bullet points. If something goes wrong, refs have signals they can use, etc. to help tie up any lose ends and then announcers can learn the new narrative almost instantly. Of course, sometimes there are unrecoverable mistakes, as Botchamania has so hilariously documented.